# Laravel / Eloquent - Prevent "deleted_at" Column From Being Returned by get() Method

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a model that looks like:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Location extends Model{

    use SoftDeletes;

    // Name of our database table
    protected $table = 'locations';

    // Column for soft deletes
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    // Columns that are mass assignable
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'address', 'city'];

}
```

When I call `Location::get()`, the `deleted_at` column is returned by default.

How do I prevent this column from being returned without explicitly specifying it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `$hidden` property like this :

```
protected $hidden = ['deleted_at'];
```

From the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json) :

> Sometimes you may wish to limit the attributes, such as passwords, that are included in your model's array or JSON representation. To do so, add a $hidden property to your model: